# Connectivity between Android mobile application and Desktop Html site

Tags: android, html, connection

Hello there Ia m working on project of vehical tracking i want to pass the float lang-latt from mobile to the static html website how should i do that ?

Comment: You could use web services for that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Webservices for that.. Google for webservices example for android and you can find out how to do that.

W3Schools has an example webservice that is written in ASP.[Here](http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx?op=CelsiusToFahrenheit) is it..

With that example webservice i have just made a sample android program to convert celsius to farenheit.

Here is the sample code

```
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import android.util.Log;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

String UserFahrenheit;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Button b=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
final EditText Med=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.MedServTextView);
final TextView Test=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.TestTextView);

b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //try{
            UserFahrenheit=Med.getText().toString();

            //String mobile=getData(UserMRN.trim());
             String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
                String METHOD_NAME = "FahrenheitToCelsius";
                String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/FahrenheitToCelsius";
                String URL = "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx?WSDL";

                SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

                Request.addProperty("Fahrenheit",UserFahrenheit.trim());

                SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                        SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                envelope.dotNet = true;
                envelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);

                HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(
                        URL);
    try{
                androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

                SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
                String Celsius;
                Celsius= String.valueOf(response.toString());
               Test.setText(Celsius);

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.getMessage();
    }



    //  }catch(Exception e){
    //      e.getMessage();
    //  }


    }
});

    }



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
return true;
}

}
```

Here i have used  a library named kSoap2..you can easily download it from the internet.

What i have done here is that i'll get the celsius value from android and send this to the server by calling the webservice using SOAP. the server then returns the farenheit value after performing the calculations.

Similarly, for your case you need to get the lattitude and longitude value from android and send it to the server using webservice and in the server use the sent values and manipulate the html page accordingly...

Try it..

Here are some of the examples..Kindly read them to understand it better..

http://androidexample.com/Dot_Net_Webservice_Call_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=100&aaid=122

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/consuming-web-services-with-ksoap--mobile-21242

Answer (score 1):

Here is the use case:
Give a Call to Web service sending your Lat-Long, and you can always save it in your back end and update your HTML page

Answer (score 0):

you can send JSON send message to website.

example

```
private static final String url_update_product ="http://10.0.2.2/get_latlong.php";
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

class SaveProductDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> 
{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() 
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... args) 
    {
String message ='your message here';

        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_NAME, message));

        final JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_update_product,"POST", params);

        try 
        {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) 
            {
                status=1;
            }
            else 
            {
                status=0;
            }
        } 
        catch (JSONException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return mesage;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
    {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        //pDialog.dismiss();

        if(status == 1)
        {
            // success
        }
        else
        {
            //failed
        }
    }
}
```

PHP

```
<?php
$response = array();
if (isset($_POST['virus_file'])) 
{
    $message = $_POST['virus_file'];
} 
else 
{
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = $message;
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```